# Sitecore Habitat Setup Issue | Error: not found : python2

Tags: habitat

All, I am facing below issue when I execute `npm install` while setting up new habitat instance by following the steps as detailed in https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started

Can you please let me know on what is the issue?

Issue is as below:

> gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
>   gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
>   gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
>   gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16\n    at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\projects\Habitat\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
>   gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the Habitat setup, but it looks like a common issue with SASS compilation.

It requires an OS/system-dependent binding file, which I believe it first tries to download from Github, but if that fails (e.g. firewalls on company network etc.) it tries to build the needed version - which requires Python 2 to be installed and available on `PATH`.

You can download Python here (choose the 2.x.x version): https://www.python.org/downloads/

### Alternative

You can also download the needed binding file yourself from the releases on Github: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

The logs should tell you which version your system needs. Then copy the file to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\<version>\`. Alternatively you can specify the path to the file with an environment variable `SASS_BINARY_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and resolved it by installing/re-installing Node.js.
https://nodejs.org/en/download
After successful installation 0pen CMD in Administrator mode and Go to your project directory to run npm install command.
Make sure the Path/npm install should be where the gulp-config.js file exist.

[image]